# Segfault 11 when trying to multiply 2 matrices

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to multiply 2 dynamically allocated arrays. I'm having 2 problems:

1. When I try unequal sized arrays like [2],[3] and [3],[2] I got a segmentation fault 11, and after staring at my allocations I still can't figure out why.
2. My final array is formatted with the correct rows and columns, but it displays all 0's.
   I'm assuming that this is because I didn't allocate the memory correctly.

-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **a, **b, **c; //pointers to arrays
    int m1_r,m1_c,m2_r,m2_c; //declaring arrays
    int i,j,k;

    printf("\n");
again://repeat if first matrixes are bad
    printf("Enter rows and columns for the first matrix.\n");//first matrix
    scanf("%d%d" ,&m1_r,&m1_c);

    printf("Enter rows and Columns for the second matrix.\n");//second matrix
    scanf("%d%d",&m2_r,&m2_c);

    if(m1_c!=m2_r) {
        printf("You tried to break my code. Nice try.");
        goto again;
    }

    //memory for first matrix
    a = malloc(m1_r * sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i < m1_r; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(m1_c * sizeof(int));
    }

    //memory for second matrix
    b = malloc(m2_r * sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i < m2_r; i++) {
        b[i] = malloc(m2_c * sizeof(int));
    }

    //memory for 3rd matrix
    c = malloc(m1_r * sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i < m2_r; i++) {
        c[i] = malloc(m2_c * sizeof(int));
    }

    //input 1st matrix
    printf("Enter the numbers of the first matrix.\n");

    for (i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<m1_c; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //input 2nd matrix
    printf("Enter the second of the first matrix.\n");

    for (i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<m1_c; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("1st matrix looks like this:\n");
    //print 1st matrix
    for (i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<m1_c; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //print 2nd matrix
    printf("\n");
    printf("2nd matrix looks like this:\n");
    //print 2st matrix
    for (i=0; i<m2_r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<m2_c; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //initialize result matrix to 0
    for(i=0; i<m2_r; i++)
        for(j=0; j<m2_c; j++) {
            c[i][j]=0;
        }

    //multipication
    for(i=0; i<m1_r; i++)
        for(j=0; j<m2_c; j++)
            for(k=0; k<m1_c; k++) {
                c[i][j]+= a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }

    //print result
    printf("\nThe result of the matrix multiplication is:");
    for(i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(k=0; k<m2_c; k++) {
            printf("%d\t", c[i][j]);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Backward `goto` is a smell.

Comment: use a ;while; loop rather than that spaghetti goto construct

Comment: regarding these kind of lines: scanf("%d%d",&m2_r,&m2_c); First, the returned value needs to be checked, to assure that two values are read.  (btw: how is the code to determine when one value ends and the next begins when your code does not allow for a delimiter between the two values?

Comment: There are a huge number of 'malloc' operations in the code, but no check is being made that the 'malloc'' operation(s) are successful.  And none of the resulting memory areas are being 'free'd.  = massive memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hell lot of bugs in your code:

First

```
//memory for 3rd matrix
c = malloc(m1_r * sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i < m2_r; i++)  <----- error: used m2_r instead of m1_r
```

You assigned m1_r and loop till m2_r.

Second

```
//input 2nd matrix
printf("Enter the second of the first matrix.\n");

for (i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {    <----- error: used m1_r instead of m2_r
    for (j = 0; j<m1_c; j++) {   <----- error: used m1_c instead of m2_c
        scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You are using rows and columns of 1st matrix.

Third

```
//initialize result matrix to 0
    for(i=0; i<m2_r; i++)     <----- error: used m2_r instead of m1_r
        for(j=0; j<m2_c; j++) {
            c[i][j]=0;
        }
```

You used row value of second matrix rather than the first matrix

Answer (score 2):

You allocate the wrong amount of memory for the third matrix:

```
c = malloc(m1_r * sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i < m2_r; i++)
```

The loop count should be the same as the number of pointers you malloc.

To avoid this sort of error, consider making a function which you pass in the dimensions and it returns the pointer.

Later on, you overwrite its bounds using different indices again:

```
for(i=0;i<m2_r;i++)
  for(j=0;j<m2_c;j++)
     {
         c[i][j]=0;
     }
```

Then you overwrite the bounds of `b` (it was `m2_r` and `m2_c`):

```
for (i=0; i<m1_r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j<m1_c; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }
}
```

To avoid this sort of error, you could use a better naming convention for your variables; and also consider using a `struct` which holds each pointer plus its dimension variables. Then you can have a function that zeroes any matrix and you only need to pass it a pointer to one of your matrix structs.

BTW if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc` then you don't need this loop at all (although you might want to have this function anyway so that you can zero a matrix).

Also you should check for success of `scanf` and `malloc`.